# Replacing a Map fragment with another Map Fragment inside Android Activity getting Error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

1. I am showing the **1st map fragment**(with Name Marker)
2. **2nd Map fragment** Showing other data. **replacing** the **1st Map--> 2nd Map** getting Below error ,when a menu button Clicked

**Problem:**

1.**Same data showing in Both Maps** after Replacing(1st and 2nd Map).

2.first time Replace is working fine, but Second time Getting the Below Mentioned **Error**

Error Caused:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error      inflating class fragment


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #26: Duplicate id 0x7f0c0113, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4994).
```

Menu Button clicked:**Replacing 1st to 2nd map Fragment**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            Fragment fr = new Route_Map_Fragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.map_Fragmentxml_mainAct_ID, fr,"fragmentRoutemap");
                            ft.addToBackStack(null);
                            ft.commit();
```

**Error Line**

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);


            View view=null;


  **Eroor Showing this Line** 
 view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.routemap_fragment4, container, false);

    return view
    }
```

Comment: Your error is in R.layout.routemap_fragment4.xml, line 26, please show the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Give different id for map fragment in second fragment in XML layout.

Comment: you have to give map fragment inside your layout with different ids.
Also try to remove the map fragment after use by
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1));
 fragmentTransaction.commit();

map1 is your id of map fragment inside your layout

Comment: i don,t want to Remove Just replace ,when Closing the 2nd Fragment 1st Should be Available

Comment: also why its Showing  1st map data in second fragment map :( Duplicate id 0x7f0c0113, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Comment: just print your layout xml (R.layout.routemap_fragment4)  file here. It will be useful for me to solve the issue.